# how to line up elements in React using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to space out elements inside a Card evenly, but they are not lined-up:

[image]

here's the code:

```
<div className="card">
    <header className="card-header">
        <div className="card-header-info">
            <p>{`#${driver.driverId}`}</p>
            <h1>{driver.name}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="card-header-info">
            <p>VEHICLE</p>
            <p>{driver.vehicleId}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="card-header-info">
            <p>HOMETOWN</p>
            <p>{driver.hometown}</p>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-header-info {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have also tried Bulma (CSS framework) columns but got nothing. Anyone know a slick technique that would achieve this goal while at the same time making the space relative to the size of the Card? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you use Card of Bulma?

Comment: Can you provide the rendered HTML? Better still provide a [mcve]. I would also consider removing the `header` wrapper and use CSS Grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following for the header element using css grid:

```
.card-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```